# What language construct does the "Box scope" in jetpack compose correspond to?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to android's jetpack compose as well as to kotlin, and I'm having a hard time figuring out how some stuff work, here I'm particularly interested in things like

```
Box {
    somecomposablefunc()
}
```

or

```
Row {
    somecomposablefunc()
}
```

Are these composable functions with no arguments, and so the whole argument list with parentheses can be omitted (as a feature of kotlin), or are they some android invention, or something else?
Sorry if I'm asking for help about well documented stuff, but I get headache from navigating both android's and kotlin's docs.

Comment: this is [trailing lambda](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas)

Comment: Start by reading a book about Kotlin. After 4-5 months you will start understanding how things are working - depending on your willingness to learn. It is not so easy. And it is perfectly ok to not understand everything with the first time... After some months you will understand also @IR42 answer...